# SQL - count number of new records based on date

Tags: sql

I have a table that refreshes hourly which contains unique case ids.  I need to return the following:

- Count of Total Cases open (INVENTORY).
- Count of Active Cases in the hour that were NOT in the table in the previous hour (NEW)
- Count of cases that WERE in the table the previous hour but are not in the current hour (CLOSED)

  ```
  Date                WorkLevel          Inventory    New     Closed
  01/30/2018 7:00 AM  Intake                   55       7          2
  01/30/2018 7:00 AM  Case Setup 1             21       1          5
  01/30/2018 7:00 AM  Case Setup 2              0       0          0
  01/30/2018 6:00 AM  Intake                   50       3          8
  01/30/2018 6:00 AM  Case Setup 1             25       4          5
  01/30/2018 6:00 AM  Case Setup 2              0       0          0
  ```

Comment: Yes, but I only know how to get the count of inventory.

Comment: To do this, you'll either need to mark each closed case for deletion and only delete it after it's been marked for an hour, or you'll need to write closed cases to another table that you can join with. Otherwise, your case table won't know what's "not there any more".

It will be helpful if we can see the case table columns.

Comment: TY Cliff.  'Inventory' is my count of case id's that are on the file when the table is populated each hour via an excel file, which I can easily find doing count(case_id) as Inventory. I grouped by date and work level.  If the case id has been closed during the hour between the most recent run and the hour prior, then it will drop off the file, and will not appear in the most recent run.  My thoughts were to somehow compare the case id's of the most current datetime and prior datetime, count the number of new case ids that were not on the table in the prior hour, and count as new.

Comment: Then do the opposite for 'Closed'. Count the number of case_id's (which will always be unique), that were in the table during the previous hour, but are no longer there in the current hour. Make that number As Closed.  Any case id that has a record in the table during the most recent run and prior run would just be counted as inventory.

Comment: So there are no deletions from this table? If that's the case, then you can derive tables with subqueries predicated on the timestamp. That is, `SELECT * from tblCase WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, casedate, GETDATE()) = 1` (of course, that's spoken in my dialect, which is MS SQL Server). Creating and joining a few of these subqueries with different predicates should shake out what you need. Let me know what platform are you using, and we can get more specific.

Comment: Correct.  No deletions.  The table just keeps adding records every hour.  We may delete old data at some point and keep only the last 6 months worth, but were not there yet. It shouldn't impact this anyway because I only need data from the most recent run and prior run.  I'm using MS SQL Server 2012, so yes that query you wrote did return the cases from the prior hour (1 hour ago).  I'm just not sure how to design the subqueries.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with your table and column names replacing my guesses, of course. This is pure fiction; I didn't build a test environment, so there may be a typo or other stupidity in there. We'll figure it out.. just let me know if you get errors or unexpected results.

```
with
   opencases as (select * from tblCase
   where datediff(hour,casedate,getdate()) = 0),
   prevcases as (select * from tblCase where datediff(hour,casedate,getdate()) = 1)
select
case when o.currdate is not null then o.currdate else p.currdate end as 'Date / Time',
case when o.worklevel is not null then o.worklevel else p.worklevel end as 'Work Level',
count(o.case_id) as 'Inventory',
sum(
   case
      when o.case_id is NOT NULL and p.case_id is NULL then 1 else 0
   end) as 'New',
sum(
   case
      when o.case_id is NULL and p.case_id is NOT NULL then 1 else 0
   end) as 'Closed'
from prevcases p
full outer join opencases o
on o.case_id = p.case_id
group by
o.currdate desc,
p.currdate desc,
o.worklevel,
p.worklevel
```

edit: not sure how you have the date and worklevel configured, but I'm guessing they'll need CASE statements also, to pull them from the correct derived table if they're not in both.

Comment: Thanks again.  I put in my fields.  One issue I found is with the summing of the case_ids. they are in a nvarchar field.  So I changed them from sum to count.  All of the data is one table so they only need to be pulled from the same table. Also the line with "on o.order_no = p.order_no".  I'm not sure which field I was supposed to put in here, but i assume its case_id.  So after making those updates I got the query to run.  Here are the 2 issues.

Comment: date                WorkLevel          Inventory    New     Closed
01/30/2018 6:00 AM  Intake                   0      25         25
01/30/2018 7:00 AM  Intake                   7       7            7

Comment: I know that didn't paste well, so heres the issue.  For the current hour 'Inventory' is displaying as zero for all work levels, and the new and closed are the same count for all work levels. I.e. 25 and 25 for Case Setup 1, 28 and 28 for Intake, etc.  For the prior hour Inventory, New and Closed are all the same count. I.e. 7, 7, 7 for Inventory, New and Closed for work level Intake.  Then Pre-Processor is 8, 8, 8.

Comment: Right... count, not sum. That's what I get for answering questions while I work on my stuff. Sorry about that!

Comment: and yes, case_id, not order_no. I started to mock this up in my database, but stopped after a short minute. That column name was a leftover. Sorry about that, too.

Comment: Focused again... I did want sum and not count. The case_id might be nvarchar, but I'm passing either a one or a zero based on the result of the case statement. What error are you getting when you use sum?

Comment: I think it might be time to whip up an SQLFiddle. I have this feeling that my solution is going to have duplicate worklevels at each hour.

Comment: The error I'm getting if I leave it as sum is "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: And as I said, if I switch from sum to count, the query runs, but the numbers are like I described in my previous comment.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: The coffee was definitely worn off. I was looking for the issue with the `CASE` statements, when you clearly said it was the third column - 'Inventory' - that needed to be `COUNT`ed and not `SUM`med. Yes, we want to `COUNT` the case_ids and `SUM` the `CASE..WHEN..THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` statements. Edited accordingly. Apologizing sincerely. I hope I'm helping more than I'm slowing you down.

Comment: you aren't slowing me down.  This is helpful.  I ran the updated query.  Still a few remaining issues though.  In the current date (most recent date/time,the work levels are not grouping properly.  I'm getting multiple rows for the same work_level (2 rows of 'Intake', 4 rows of ' Reviewer', etc with different inventory counts.  And in the prior date (one hour ago) results, the work levels are grouping ok, but there are no counts in the inventory column, only in the new and closed columns.

Comment: This is good stuff. I'm testing the limits of my imagination, though. Can you sanitize and provide some sample data, though? Just case_id, timestamp, and worklevel, across several hours. Those are the only three columns I need... I can tell this looks sensitive.

Comment: Date                           WorkLevel          Inventory    New     Closed
02/02/2018 2:00 PM  Intake                            0         0          18
02/02/2018 2:00 PM  Case Setup 1                0         0          2
02/02/2018 2:00 PM  Case Setup 2                0         0          46
02/02/2018 3:00 PM  Case Setup 1                50       3          8
02/02/2018 3:00 PM  Case Setup 1                25       4          5
02/02/2018 3:00 PM  Case Setup 1                  5      6           8

Comment: I'm not sure how to format that sample data as a table.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, what you provided is actually your desired output. I need to see what your input is.. that is, what your spreadsheet looks like.